# using minus sign when creating a calculated column in power bi with a column and measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a column in Power BI using following criteria. Any assistance is appreciated.

**What I need:** I need to compare a column with a measure and get 1 or 0. The measure must be in negative.

I tried to add minus sign in front of measure but it does not give me the value that should be in the new col that I am creating.
I also tried to create the measure by multiplying it with -1 to get negative measure. I get the negative measure, but when I use that measure to create the col it does not yield me the right values.

Can you please tell me how I can add a "-" minus sign and have the right value in the created column.

for e.g.

| Task | Revenue | NEW_COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -A | -30 | 1 |
| -B | -20 | 0 |
| -C | 10 | 1 |
| -A | 30 | 0 |
| -B | 50 | 1 |
| -C | -2 | 0 |

A measure value that I have = a_measure = 27.58

Above table is what I get when I apply -- **This does not work:** col_name = IF(table1[Revenue]<=(-[a_measure]),"1","0")

| Task | Revenue | NEW_COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -A | -30 | 1 |
| -B | -20 | 0 |
| -C | 10 | 0 |
| -A | 30 | 0 |
| -B | 50 | 0 |
| -C | -2 | 0 |

Above is the col I get when I apply following --
**This works:** col_name = IF(table1[Revenue]<=(-27.58),"1","0")

**This does not work:** col_name = IF(table1[Revenue]<=(-[a_measure]),"1","0")

I need to use the measure in the formula as the value in the measure is subject to change. the 2nd table is what i need.

Comment: try ``-1*[a_measure]``

Comment: hi Umut, this one also does not work. i tried: col_name = IF(table1[Revenue]<=([a_measure]*-1),"1","0")                                    and col_name = IF(table1[Revenue]<=-1*([a_measure]),"1","0")               and col_name = IF(table1[Revenue]<=(([a_measure])*-1),"1","0")            none worked

Comment: Are you sure ‘’[a_measure]’’ is a decimal number ?

Comment: hi Umut, yes it is a decimal number. and this must be converted into negative when used in the if statement.

Comment: hi Umut, were you indicating that it may work if it not a decimal value? i tried keeping it a whole number it still did not work.

Comment: Strange… you can try to multiply -1 within the previous measure maybe…

Comment: Or change the formula as  >= without multiplying -1

Comment: i tried to calculate the measure with this formula: a measure = (std.p*(sqrt(1-0.89)))*-1. i got the - value in the measure.  when i had the -ve measure value i did not use the * -1 in the if statement. but that also did not work when used in the if statement to get the new_col.

Comment: i will put this question in another way. how would i compare each cell of a column with a measure value? so in excel we can lock a cell like this: $F$4 and then compare it with each cell of a column. how would we do this in power bi?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this forumla

col_name = IF(table1[Revenue]<=([a_measure]),"- 1"," - 0")

Comment: hi Pushkin i need to use "minus" sign with the a_measure.

Comment: i see, this might be the solution.

  VAR __a_measure = (your measure
RETURN
IF(table1[Revenue]<= ([a_measure]) ,"-0 * a-measure", "-1 * a-measure")

Tested this it worked for me